# Spanish equivalent for "page-turner"

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones, solicitud-de-término

Is there a Spanish expression equivalent to "page-turner", as in "this book is a real page-turner"?

So far, I've asked one Mexican friend, who just shrugged and looked online, where reverso.net suggested "tornero de página", which doesn't sound right to me. So, there might not be a Mexican equivalent, but maybe there is one from another country? Or maybe this phrase just doesn't translate well?

De antemano agradecidos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spanish language usually requires more words than English to express the same concept, and the expressions do not need to be literal translations of the English one. The first choice that came into my mind is *este libro **se lee [de una sentada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XaoEW7y)***. If you need a shorter expression, you just can say that *ese libro **es muy [absorbente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0CjIsyE)***.

In the first case, *de una sentada* refers to the act of sitting down to read the book, and not standing up until you finish it. The second expression refers to the book being capable of absorbing your mind until you finish it. By following the previous link you can find the following meaning for the word *absorber* along with just the example we need:

> 4. tr. Atraer la atención de alguien o mantener a una persona ocupada por completo. *La novela conseguía absorber la atención del lector. El estudio la absorbe.*

Answer (score 2):

We don't have an expression like "page-turner".

We use to say "me devoré el libro en una tarde".

For example:

> Hoy vengo con otra reseña de un libro que me devoré en una noche

But it isn't a rule, you can say in different ways.

Comment: Precisamente no..."page-turner" describes a book that you just can't put down. As in, once you start reading it, you can't stop turning the pages until you're done.

Comment: ok, we used to say "me devoré el libro en una tarde" example "Hoy vengo con otra reseña de un libro que me devoré en una noche", but it isn´t a rule, you can say in different ways. we don´t have an expression like "page-turner"

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include your new choice (that seems perfectly valid to me). Bear in mind that future visitors may not think of reading the comments while looking for the answer.

Comment: AlejoAispuro thanks for your answer. As you see, I have edited it so it contains what you mentioned in comments, as @CarlosAlejo had suggested. Try to give a read to [answer] to get the basic guidelines on what is a proper answer here, which should contain some explanations, examples, tips, etc. Thanks and welcome to [spanish.se].

Answer (score 2):

---

Que tal? Sobre la expresión "*page-turner*"

Simplemente puedo añadir a lo expuesto, que una forma sencilla de decir "page-turner" es del tirón, "**Leí el libro de un tirón**" "*lo leí del tirón*" ó "*de un tirón*", depende de tu zona,  indicando con ello todas las acepciones que más arriba aparecen, de una vez, de un golpe, de una sentada, sin parar...

Espero haya ayudado. Saludos!

Diego M.